# Mariadb Galera can't start second node

Tags: mariadb, azure, galera

**EDIT: the both server was in Azure**

I tried to install Galera replication on two server. On my first server the "bootstrap" node will correctly start.

When i try to start the second node with the command :

```
systemctl start mariadb
```

I'll got this error :

```
Mar 27 10:19:05 NODE_2 mariadbd[652655]:         Local state: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
Mar 27 10:19:05 NODE_2 mariadbd[652655]: 2024-03-27 10:19:05 1 [Note] WSREP: Server status change connected -> joiner
Mar 27 10:19:05 NODE_2 mariadbd[652655]: 2024-03-27 10:19:05 0 [Note] WSREP: Running: 'wsrep_sst_mariabackup --role 'joiner' --address 'my_own_domain' --datadir '/var/lib/mysql/' --parent 652655 --progress 0 --mysqld-args --wsrep_start_position=0000000>
Mar 27 10:19:05 NODE_2 mariadbd[652655]: 2024-03-27 10:19:05 0 [Note] WSREP: Joiner monitor thread started to monitor
Mar 27 10:19:05 NODE_2 mariadbd[652665]: WSREP_SST: [INFO] mariabackup SST started on joiner (20240327 10:19:05.290)
Mar 27 10:19:05 NODE_2 mariadbd[652665]: WSREP_SST: [INFO] SSL configuration: CA='', CAPATH='', CERT='', KEY='', MODE='DISABLED', encrypt='0' (20240327 10:19:05.326)
Mar 27 10:19:05 NODE_2 mariadbd[652665]: WSREP_SST: [INFO] Logging all stderr of SST/mariadb-backup to syslog (20240327 10:19:05.430)
Mar 27 10:19:05 NODE_2 -wsrep-sst-joiner[652829]: Streaming with mbstream
Mar 27 10:19:05 NODE_2 -wsrep-sst-joiner[652830]: Using socat as streamer
Mar 27 10:19:05 NODE_2 -wsrep-sst-joiner[652861]: Evaluating timeout -k 310 300 socat -u TCP-LISTEN:4444,reuseaddr stdio | '/usr//bin/mbstream' -x; RC=( ${PIPESTATUS[@]} )
Mar 27 10:19:05 NODE_2 mariadbd[652655]: 2024-03-27 10:19:05 1 [Note] WSREP: ####### IST uuid:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 f: 0, l: 254, STRv: 3
Mar 27 10:19:05 NODE_2 mariadbd[652655]: 2024-03-27 10:19:05 1 [Note] WSREP: IST receiver addr using tcp://my_own_domain:4568
Mar 27 10:19:05 NODE_2 mariadbd[652655]: 2024-03-27 10:19:05 1 [Warning] WSREP: Failed to prepare for incremental state transfer: Failed to open IST listener at tcp://my_own_domain:4568', asio error 'Failed to listen: bind: Cannot assign requested addr>
Mar 27 10:19:05 NODE_2 mariadbd[652655]:          at ./galerautils/src/gu_asio_stream_react.cpp:listen():788': 99 (Cannot assign requested address)
Mar 27 10:19:05 NODE_2 mariadbd[652655]:          at ./galera/src/ist.cpp:prepare():319. IST will be unavailable.
Mar 27 10:19:05 NODE_2 mariadbd[652655]: 2024-03-27 10:19:05 0 [Note] WSREP: Member 1.0 (NODE_2) requested state transfer from '*any*'. Selected 0.0 (NODE_1)(SYNCED) as donor.
Mar 27 10:19:05 NODE_2 mariadbd[652655]: 2024-03-27 10:19:05 0 [Note] WSREP: Shifting PRIMARY -> JOINER (TO: 254)
Mar 27 10:19:05 NODE_2 mariadbd[652655]: 2024-03-27 10:19:05 1 [Note] WSREP: Requesting state transfer: success, donor: 0
Mar 27 10:19:05 NODE_2 mariadbd[652655]: 2024-03-27 10:19:05 1 [Note] WSREP: Resetting GCache seqno map due to different histories.
Mar 27 10:19:05 NODE_2 mariadbd[652655]: 2024-03-27 10:19:05 1 [Note] WSREP: GCache history reset: d4e095a6-ec15-11ee-9956-0ab8ed89b3e9:0 -> d4e095a6-ec15-11ee-9956-0ab8ed89b3e9:254
Mar 27 10:19:05 NODE_2 mariadbd[652655]: 2024-03-27 10:19:05 0 [Warning] WSREP: 0.0 (NODE_1): State transfer to 1.0 (NODE_2) failed: -42 (No message of desired type)
Mar 27 10:19:05 NODE_2 mariadbd[652655]: 2024-03-27 10:19:05 0 [ERROR] WSREP: ./gcs/src/gcs_group.cpp:gcs_group_handle_join_msg():1172: Will never receive state. Need to abort.
Mar 27 10:19:05 NODE_2 mariadbd[652655]: 2024-03-27 10:19:05 0 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: terminating thread
Mar 27 10:19:05 NODE_2 mariadbd[652655]: 2024-03-27 10:19:05 0 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: joining thread
Mar 27 10:19:05 NODE_2 mariadbd[652655]: 2024-03-27 10:19:05 0 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: closing backend
Mar 27 10:19:07 NODE_2 mariadbd[652655]: 2024-03-27 10:19:07 0 [Note] WSREP: (6f46a84f-9c6c, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') turning message relay requesting off
Mar 27 10:19:07 NODE_2 mariadbd[652655]: 2024-03-27 10:19:07 0 [Note] WSREP: view(view_id(NON_PRIM,60a6097c-81cf,4) memb {
Mar 27 10:19:07 NODE_2 mariadbd[652655]:         6f46a84f-9c6c,0
Mar 27 10:19:07 NODE_2 mariadbd[652655]: } joined {
Mar 27 10:19:07 NODE_2 mariadbd[652655]: } left {
Mar 27 10:19:07 NODE_2 mariadbd[652655]: } partitioned {
Mar 27 10:19:07 NODE_2 mariadbd[652655]:         60a6097c-81cf,0
Mar 27 10:19:07 NODE_2 mariadbd[652655]: })
Mar 27 10:19:07 NODE_2 mariadbd[652655]: 2024-03-27 10:19:07 0 [Note] WSREP: PC protocol downgrade 1 -> 0
Mar 27 10:19:07 NODE_2 mariadbd[652655]: 2024-03-27 10:19:07 0 [Note] WSREP: view((empty))
Mar 27 10:19:07 NODE_2 mariadbd[652655]: 2024-03-27 10:19:07 0 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: closed
Mar 27 10:19:07 NODE_2 mariadbd[652655]: 2024-03-27 10:19:07 0 [Note] WSREP: /usr/sbin/mariadbd: Terminated.
Mar 27 10:19:07 NODE_2 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
```

And on the first node i don't seen any error, but sometimes i got this log :

```
2024-03-27 10:24:38 1 [Note] WSREP: ================================================
View:
  id: d4e095a6-ec15-11ee-9956-0ab8ed89b3e9:320
  status: primary
  protocol_version: 4
  capabilities: MULTI-MASTER, CERTIFICATION, PARALLEL_APPLYING, REPLAY, ISOLATION, PAUSE, CAUSAL_READ, INCREMENTAL_WS, UNORDERED, PREORDERED, STREAMING, NBO
  final: no
  own_index: 1
  members(2):
        0: 361330d2-ec24-11ee-9a13-2f9126bb440d, NODE_2
        1: 60a6097c-ec23-11ee-81cf-fe2df31bd94f, NODE_1
=================================================
2024-03-27 10:24:38 1 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
2024-03-27 10:24:38 1 [Note] WSREP: Lowest cert index boundary for CC from group: 320
2024-03-27 10:24:38 1 [Note] WSREP: Min available from gcache for CC from group: 1
2024-03-27 10:24:39 0 [Note] WSREP: Member 0.0 (NODE_2) requested state transfer from '*any*'. Selected 1.0 (NODE_1)(SYNCED) as donor.
2024-03-27 10:24:39 0 [Note] WSREP: Shifting SYNCED -> DONOR/DESYNCED (TO: 320)
2024-03-27 10:24:39 1 [Note] WSREP: Detected STR version: 1, req_len: 80, req: STRv1
2024-03-27 10:24:39 1 [Warning] WSREP: Joiner didn't provide IST connection info - cert. index preload impossible, bailing out.
2024-03-27 10:24:39 0 [Warning] WSREP: 1.0 (NODE_1): State transfer to 0.0 (NODE_2) failed: -42 (No message of desired type)
2024-03-27 10:24:39 0 [Note] WSREP: Shifting DONOR/DESYNCED -> JOINED (TO: 320)
2024-03-27 10:24:39 0 [Note] WSREP: Processing event queue:... -nan% (0/0 events) complete.
2024-03-27 10:24:39 0 [Note] WSREP: Member 1.0 (NODE_1) synced with group.
2024-03-27 10:24:39 0 [Note] WSREP: Processing event queue:...100.0% (1/1 events) complete.
2024-03-27 10:24:39 0 [Note] WSREP: Shifting JOINED -> SYNCED (TO: 320)
2024-03-27 10:24:39 1 [Note] WSREP: Server NODE_1 synced with group
2024-03-27 10:24:40 0 [Note] WSREP: (60a6097c-81cf, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') turning message relay requesting off
2024-03-27 10:24:40 0 [Note] WSREP: Deferred close timer started for socket with remote endpoint: tcp://IP_NODE_2:37668
2024-03-27 10:24:40 0 [Note] WSREP: forgetting 361330d2-9a13 (tcp://IP_NODE_2:4567)
2024-03-27 10:24:40 0 [Note] WSREP: Node 60a6097c-81cf state prim
2024-03-27 10:24:40 0 [Note] WSREP: view(view_id(PRIM,60a6097c-81cf,71) memb {
        60a6097c-81cf,0
} joined {
} left {
} partitioned {
        361330d2-9a13,0
})
2024-03-27 10:24:40 0 [Note] WSREP: save pc into disk
2024-03-27 10:24:40 0 [Note] WSREP: forgetting 361330d2-9a13 (tcp://IP_NODE_2:4567)
2024-03-27 10:24:40 0 [Note] WSREP: New COMPONENT: primary = yes, bootstrap = no, my_idx = 0, memb_num = 1
2024-03-27 10:24:40 0 [Note] WSREP: Deferred close timer handle_wait Operation aborted. for 0x55dcb95ab450
2024-03-27 10:24:40 0 [Note] WSREP: Deferred close timer destruct
2024-03-27 10:24:40 0 [Note] WSREP: STATE_EXCHANGE: sent state UUID: 38b2761b-ec24-11ee-938b-86ab48f03ace
2024-03-27 10:24:40 0 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: sent state msg: 38b2761b-ec24-11ee-938b-86ab48f03ace
2024-03-27 10:24:40 0 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: got state msg: 38b2761b-ec24-11ee-938b-86ab48f03ace from 0 (NODE_1)
```

Sometimes i also have this error :

```
 requested state transfer from '*any*', but it is impossible to select State Transfer donor: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Any idea how to make the two cluster workin?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue with my cluster before. In my case, the problem was the lack of communication between the servers. I was using a DNS address in the configuration to communicate with the other server. What I did was change it to the IP address. Try this test: if you're using DNS, switch to the IP address. Also, check for any blocking. Run a TELNET between the servers on the communication port (4567) to see if there's any blocking.

Comment: I try both, dns name or IP same error the port are open